# Why does the scrollbar for Chrome users hide sometimes?

Tags: browser-compatibility

We're building a SP2010 SP1 site.

For users on Chrome, sometimes the scrollbar doesn't display. The user has to refresh 1-10 times until the scrollbar appears.

Why does Chrome have trouble consistently displaying the scrollbar in SP2010?

Answer (score 5):

I've confirmed this link is a solution: http://kyleschaeffer.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-scrolling/

Our scrollbar always works, scripting doesn't break, and we haven't seen any negative side effects!

Comment: This is great!  We've had this issue in our custom site for a long time now.  Glad I can propose a solution.

Answer (score 4):

While it's not an "official" post, [the Microsoft blog](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blog/Pages/BlogPost.aspx?pID=973), along with several other posts does state that Chrome is supported post-SP1, along with IE9 in IE8 standards mode. The addition of Chrome support in Service Pack 1 includes both SharePoint and Office Web Apps.

I have seen this issue in both vanilla environments, as well as those with some pretty extreme customization, and it only presents itself when the SharePoint managed scrolling is enabled. I haven't been able to identify a fix, but my (caveat this is my opinion) thoughts are that it stems from the JavaScript that does the screen size calculations to scroll the main content div. If the script fires slightly out of order and grabs the height of the content div before all of the content has loaded, it fails to add the scrollbar since it doesn't think there is enough content to warrant it.

I've thought about browser sniffing, and if the user agent shows desktop Chrome, manually calling that script operation a second time to try and validate that's the hang up, but I haven't really had enough time to sit down and troubleshoot it.

Comment: That's really interesting. We're gonna try it out and report back how it goes.

Comment: Anybody tried this? http://kyleschaeffer.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-scrolling

Comment: I've confirmed this link is a solution: http://kyleschaeffer.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-scrolling/ Our scrollbar always works, scripting doesn't break, and we haven't seen any negative side effects!

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that Chrome is not a supported browser in SharePoint 2010:

[TechNet: Plan browser support (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx)

Comment: It is if you're running Service Pack 1 or greater.

Comment: I didn't believe it, but here is the source to the claim that SP1 supports Chrome: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff925944.aspx, though note this is for OWA, I can't find one for SP2010 itself.

Comment: Note that link is for OWA only, not SharePoint Server as a whole.  You'll also note that the original link was last updated in Sept 2011, after the release of SP1.

Comment: We are on SP1, and still experience this issue. (Someone told me this would be the fix, but it wasn't. :) We started off without SP1.)

Comment: This topic is a little outdated now; the browser support planning for SharePoint 2010 now reflects support for Chrome.

Comment: Yep, they "support everything", but Chrome still does not show the scroll bar and will also add two of the same entry to the People Editor when picked from the People Picker.  Also, Project Server has some pages that are IE-only.

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix could solve this, check the article on my blog "sharepoint 2010 scrolling issue in chrome" article at http://tad.co.in/?p=693

Comment: We  require relevant answers and disclosure of any affiliation with  products or websites. Please see [May I promote products or websites I  am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines.

Comment: This is indeed a clean approach to the problem - the KyleSchaeffer solution is not clean AT ALL (lots of side-effects). Upvoting.

Comment: Nice solution. I have used it, too. Could you paste the code in your answer as well?

Comment: This is a broken link

Answer (score 1):

Here's the only clean solution I found to solve this problem. The KyleSchaeffer solution is not clean and comes with loads of side-effects: http://withinsharepoint.com/archives/256 
This code was cleaned from another guy who posted it on github: https://gist.github.com/4224245 . It basically re-executes the function on webkit browsers if it hasn't been executed the first time. It's as clean and accessible as it gets.