# 2010 Sharepoint site is not showing scroll bars in IE 11

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, ie-11

We switched to IE 11 from IE 8 and the vertical scroll bars are gone on our SharePoint 2010 sites. I know about the compatibility view, but I am not clear what is the best way to implement it in the master page . Also, I  would like to know what are my other options and what is the most probable culprit.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hi I would suggest that you implement not by code but by getting your AD group policy team to setup IE8 Compatibility mode via group policy.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn321457.aspx

Answer (score 0):

We just found a hack/fix for this issue. (Our users were using Chrome to workaround it, but there seems to be a [known issue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/58511) with Chrome where sometimes the Ribbon doesn't load properly and thus disables the Submit button). Solution for IE 11 was:

- Edited the FormServer.aspx file directly on the Server
- Added the following code in the `<head>` tag:

  `<script type="text/javascript">`
  `setTimeout(function(){ document.body.scroll = "yes"; }, 1000);`
  `</script>`

Interestingly only a few of our forms had this problem - we never determined why some were affected and others were not. The ones that were unaffected still had `scroll="no"` in the body tag, but the scroll-bar appeared (starting from below the ribbon, rather than full height).

Obviously it's an unsupported fix and would need to be reapplied after patching, however we couldn't get anything else to work. We did try other fixes, and while [this article](http://kyleschaeffer.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-scrolling/) seems to have a fix, it didn't work for us. (Does InfoPath even use v4.Master when rendering a form?). We also looked at the InfoPath Form Viewer Web Part, but it had problems rendering a Rich Text control (as the Ribbon isn't present).

Comment: the SharePoint ribbon doesnt load properly 9/10 times. Honestly we would be better of haveing it always visible or not haveing it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Make a change in the masterpages from:

> meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"

to:

> meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"